# Some hostnames in hosts file do not resolve

Tags: linux, networking, hosts

My hosts file has two entries in the same range:

```
84.xxx.xxx.111 serverA  
84.xxx.xxx.112 serverB
```

I can ping serverA BUT I can't ping serverB for which I get Unknown Host.

`/etc/resolv` is fine [serverA works], I restarted the network service, DNS server is pingable, no iptables.
I can ping both IPs
Can you help about with some ideas please?
I have more entries in the hosts file they all work apart from those.

Comment: Hello and welcome and StackExchange Unix & Linux, please take the time to read the [tour]. Your quesiton shows some information but very badly formatted and it makes it hard to understand. provide real syntax example of your hosts file please (you can mask your IP not a problem just sdhow the full syntax in it.  Also what is your distribution, resolv.conf should not be edit manually in most Linux nowadays.

Comment: Also it's confuse are your talkiing about `/etc/hosts` file or about `/etc/resolv` you should provide both IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote out those IPs and hostnames again in the hosts file and now it works. It must have some character encoding that was wrong. I don't know how because they were all copy pasted from the terminal!